# Why is PassportJS in Node not removing session on logout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logout, passport.js

I am having trouble getting my system to log out with PassportJS. It seems the logout route is being called, but its not removing the session. I want it to return 401, if the user is not logged in in specific route. I call authenticateUser to check if user is logged in.

Thanks a lot!

```
/******* This in index.js *********/
// setup passport for username & passport authentication
adminToolsSetup.setup(passport);

// admin tool login/logout logic
app.post("/adminTool/login",
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/adminTool/index.html',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: false })
);
app.get('/adminTool/logout', adminToolsSetup.authenticateUser, function(req, res){
    console.log("logging out");
    console.log(res.user);
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});


// ******* This is in adminToolSetup ********
// Setting up user authentication to be using user name and passport as authentication method,
// this function will fetch the user information from the user name, and compare the password     for authentication
exports.setup = function(passport) {
    setupLocalStrategy(passport);
    setupSerialization(passport);
}

function setupLocalStrategy(passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            console.log('validating user login');
            dao.retrieveAdminbyName(username, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                // has password then compare password
                var hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest("hex");
                if (user.adminPassword != hashedPassword) {
                    console.log('incorrect password');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                console.log('user validated');
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
}

function setupSerialization(passport) {
    // serialization
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("serialize user");
        done(null, user.adminId);
    });

    // de-serialization
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        dao.retrieveUserById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log("de-serialize user");
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}

// authenticating the user as needed
exports.authenticateUser = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.send("401 unauthorized", 401);
    }
    next();
}
```

Comment: In my code I call `req.logOut()` with upper O case, but regarding the [guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/logout/) your code should work too.

Comment: I have tried lots of solutions but none of them worked for me. Finally, I tried to update package passport@0.2.0 to passport@0.2.2 and it works!

Answer (score 92):

**Brice’s answer is great**, but I still noticed an important distinction to make; the Passport guide suggests using `.logout()` (also aliased as `.logOut()`) as such:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/'); //Can fire before session is destroyed?
});
```

But as mentioned above, this is unreliable. I found it behaved as expected when implementing Brice’s suggestion like this:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res){
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    res.redirect('/'); //Inside a callback… bulletproof!
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just get 'Object #<Session> has no method 'destroy'' as errormessage

Comment: @schlenger Hmm, the above is using Express 3. Are you using version 4?

Comment: Be careful because, in the example given here, the usage of session.destroy assumes use of the express-sessions module. Other session modules (e.g. mozilla node-client-sessions) adds a destroy method that returns synchronously only and disregards any callback pararmeter. In which case your code will hang

Comment: Are you basing this on `client-sessions`? It's destroy function doesn't take an argument: https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions/blob/master/lib/client-sessions.js#L425

Comment: ok I use your second method. The session file in the sessions folder is deleted and the session cookie is removed from the client, but the Node server shows following error message in the console: `[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...` how could I fix this?

Comment: Just a quick question, is it necessary to send credentials from front-end when calling this /logout function?

Answer (score 43):

Ran into the same issue. Using `req.session.destroy();` instead of `req.logout();` works, but I don't know if this is the best practice.

Comment: Adding req.session.destroy(); worked for me, I had the same problem

Comment: req.session.destroy(); worked for me too and remember to clear you cookies with res.clearCookie('cookiename'). However does anyone knows what exactly req.logout() do?

Comment: @WebHrushi you can find the function in passport/lib/passport/http/request.js. 
Today both versions stopped working for me, redirect seems in both ways called before the session is finally destroyed. On the redirected page both ways described here seem to be working fine.

Comment: I don't like the idea of not using `req.logout()`, for forward compatibility and whatnot, so I just added `req.session.destroy();` after `req.logout()` and that works fine.

Answer (score 16):

`session.destroy` may be insufficient, to make sure the user is fully logged out you have to clear session cookie as well.

The issue here is that if your application is also used as an API for a single page app (not recommended but quite common) then there can be some request(s) being processed by express that started before logout and end after logout. If this were the case then this longer running request will restore the session in redis after it was deleted. And because the browser still has the same cookie the next time you open the page you will be successfully logged in.

```
req.session.destroy(function() {
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

That's the what maybe happening otherwise:

1. Req 1 (any request) is received
2. Req 1 loads session from redis to memory
3. Logout req received
4. Logout req loads session
5. Logout req destroys session
6. Logout req sends redirect to the browser (cookie is not removed)
7. Req 1 completes processing
8. Req 1 saves the session from memory to redis
9. User opens the page without login dialog because both the cookie and the session are in place

Ideally you need to use token authentication for api calls and only use sessions in web app that only loads pages, but even if your web app is only used to obtain api tokens this race condition is still possible.

Comment: This solves the issue on the client, rather than on the server, which seems insecure.  if `connect.sid` gets hijacked before you log out it shouldn't allow another party to login as you after you have logged out.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue, and it turned out to not be a problem with Passport functions at all, but rather in the way I was calling my `/logout` route. I used fetch to call the route:

**(Bad)**

```
fetch('/auth/logout')
  .then([other stuff]);
```

Turns out doing that doesn't send cookies so the session isn't continued and I guess the `res.logout()` gets applied to a different session? At any rate, doing the following fixes it right up:

**(Good)**

```
fetch('/auth/logout', { credentials: 'same-origin' })
  .then([other stuff]);
```

Comment: Was searching for 4 hours before ending up on this answer, a silly mistake but thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issues, capital O fixed it;

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res){
  req.logOut()  // <-- not req.logout();
  res.redirect('/')
});
```

Edit: this is no longer an issue.

Comment: The current version of Passport accepts either logOut or logout (same with login and logIn)

Comment: `logout` and `logOut` were aliased to each other in 2015:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blame/07bff37406241b0cf8db35986788d2dadbf93763/lib/framework/connect.js#L35

Answer (score 6):

I used both `req.logout()` and `req.session.destroy()` and works fine.

```
server.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy(()=>{
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Just to mention, i use Redis as session store.

Comment: your code can lead to an unexpected behavior if the cache is slow or if you have a middle ware running after the logout logic, you should use  req.session.destroy(()=> res.redirect("/"));

Comment: `session.destroy` is asynchronous and  requires a callback. You should call `res.redirect('/');` in that callback.

Answer (score 5):

I was recently having this same issue and none of the answers fixed the issue for me. Could be wrong but it does seem to have to do with a race condition.

Changing the session details to the options below seems to have fixed the issue for me. I have tested it about 10 times or so now and everything seems to be working correctly.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
```

Basically I just changed `saveUninitialized` and `resave` from `true` to `false`. That seems to have fixed the issue.

Just for reference I'm using the standard `req.logout();` method in my logout path. I'm not using the session destroy like other people have mentioned.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: I was having issues with both logout and login occasionally not sticking, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: @TomHughes Glad it helped!!

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me so I will share mine

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'some_secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: {maxAge: 1000} // this is the key
}))
```

and

```
router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logOut()
    req.redirect('/')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Destroying session by yourself looks weird.
I faced with this issue having next configuration:

```
"express": "^4.12.3",
"passport": "^0.2.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
```

I should say that this configuration **works well**. 
The reason of my issue was in custom `sessionStore` that I defined here:

```
app.use(expressSession({
    ...
    store: dbSessionStore,
    ...
}));
```

To be sure that your issue here too just comment store line and run without session persisting. If it will work you should dig into your custom session store. In my case `set` method was defined wrong. When you use `req.logout()` session store `destroy()` method not invoked as I thought before. Instead invoked `set` method with updated session.

Good luck, I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I got an experience that, sometime it's doesn't work because you fail to to setup passport properly.
For example, I do `vhost`, but on main app I setup passport like this which is wrong.

**app.js** (why wrong ? please see blockqoute below)

```
require('./modules/middleware.bodyparser')(app);
require('./modules/middleware.passport')(app);
require('./modules/middleware.session')(app);
require('./modules/app.config.default.js')(app, express);

// default router across domain
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/loginController'));
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

// vhost setup
app.use(vhost('sub1.somehost.dev', require('./app.host.sub1.js')));
app.use(vhost('somehost.dev', require('./app.host.main.js')));
```

actually, it must not be able to login, but I manage to do that because, I continue to do more mistake. by putting another passport setup here, so session form `app.js` available to `app.host.sub1.js`

**app.host.sub1.js**

```
// default app configuration
require('./modules/middleware.passport')(app);
require('./modules/app.config.default.js')(app, express);
```

So, when I want to logout... it's not work because `app.js` was do something wrong by start initialize `passport.js` before `express-session.js`, which is wrong !!.

However, this code can solved the issues anyway as others mention.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        // destroy session data
        req.session = null;

        // redirect to homepage
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

> But in my case the correct way is... swap the **express-session.js** before **passport.js**

[document](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) also mention

> Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is
>   recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use
>   express.session() before passport.session() to ensure that the login
>   session is restored in the correct order.

So, resolved logout issue on my case by..

**app.js**

```
require('./modules/middleware.bodyparser')(app);
require('./modules/middleware.session')(app);
require('./modules/middleware.passport')(app);
require('./modules/app.config.default.js')(app, express);


// default router across domain
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/loginController'));
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

**app.host.sub1.js**

```
// default app configuration
require('./modules/app.config.default.js')(app, express);
```

and now `req.logout();` is work now.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are multiple possible causes of this issue. In my case the problem was wrong order of declarations i.e. the logout endpoint was declared before passport initialization. The right order is:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

simply adding req.logOut(); solved this issue ; "O" should be capitalized

Comment: Welcome! Please refer to this guide for improving your answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Turned out that my version of passport wasn't compatible with Express 4.0. Just need to install an older version.

```
    npm install --save express@3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
app.get('/user', restrictRoute, function (req, res) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate,
              max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
});
```

It makes sure that your page won't get stored in cache

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a programmer, that suggests to remove user of req:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res){
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    req.user = null;
    res.redirect('/'); //Inside a callback… bulletproof!
  });
});
```

**Reason:**
we need to remove from req(passportjs also doing this but async way) because there is no use of user data after logout
even this will save memory and also might be passportjs found user data and may create new session and redirect(but not yet happen)
By the ways, this is our responsibility to remove irrelevant thing. PassportJS assign data into req.user after login and also remove if we use req.logout() but it may not works properly some times as NodeJS Asynchronous in nature

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem with Passport 0.3.2.

When I use Custom Callback for the passport login and signup the problem persisted.

The problem was solved by upgrading to Passport 0.4.0 and adding the lines

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logOut();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using passport authentication which uses it's own session via the `connect.sid` cookie this simplest way of dealing with logging out is letting passport handle the session.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    req.logOut()
    return res.redirect('/') // Handle valid logout
  }

  return res.status(401) // Handle unauthenticated response
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All examples here do a redirect after the req.session.destroy. 
But do realise that Express will create a new session instantly for the page you are redirecting to. 
In combination with Postman I found the strange behaviour that doing a Passport-Login right after the logout gives the effect that Passport is successful but cannot store the user id to the session file. The reason is that Postman needs to update the cookie in all requests for this group, and this takes a while. 
Also the redirect in the callback of the destroy does not help.

I solved it by not doing a redirect but just returning a json message.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue.

What I did was to use `req.session.destroy(function (err) {});` on the server side and on the client side, whenever they logout:

```
const logout = () => {
    const url = '/users/logout'
    fetch(url)
    setTimeout(function () {
      location.reload();    }, 500);
```

That way, when refreshing the page, the user is without session. Just make sure you are redirecting to the correct page if no one is authenticated.

Not the best approach, perhaps, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to support. I would suggest fixing the code formatting in your answer. The main snippet you posted isn't valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually regenerating the session:

```js
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    req.session.regenerate(err => {
        err && console.log(err);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

This does not remove other data (like passport) from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Why will this code work? Can you provide more detail around that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting the `withCredentials: true` on my `axios.post` request to the logout route. I guess the required credentials to identify the session weren't being sent over so the req.logOut() had no effect (I also noticed that `req.user` was undefined on the log out route, which was a big clue)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve a similar problem by changing the code in my client where I made the request, replacing the following:

```js
 const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/auth/logout");
```

with this:

```js
window.open("http://localhost:4000/auth/logout", "_self");
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31386517)

Answer (score 0):

For me `req.logout` worked but I don't why `req.logout()` not working. How function call is not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I do this

window.open(`http://localhost:4000/auth/logout`,  "_self");

in the function before window.open call to e.preventDefault()

this is recommended because when you do click in log out Button you refresh the page, and the function isn't call it

function logout(e) {
e.preventDefault()
window.open(`http://localhost:4000/auth/logout`,  "_self");
}

3 January 2022

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your method from `POST` to `DELETE` on your `/logout` route.

```
app.delete('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
 req.logOut((err) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  return res.redirect('/');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.logOut()
```

and

```
req.logOut()
```

didn't worked for me.

For me this worked just fine:

```
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  req.cookies = null;
 res.json({message: 'Logged out'})
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You shoulde be using req.logout() to destroy the session in the browser.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/'); // whatever the route to your default page is
});
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case, using a callback passed to `req.session.destroy` helped only some of the time and I had to resort to this hack:

```
req.session.destroy();
setTimeout(function() {
    res.redirect "/";
}, 2000);
```

I don't know why that's the only solution that I've been able to get to work, but unfortunately @JulianLloyd's answer did not work for me consistently.

It may have something to do with the fact that my live login page uses SSL (I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on the staging site or my localhost). There may be something else going on in my app too; I'm using the derby-passport module since my app is using the [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) framework, so it's difficult to isolate the problem.

It's clearly a timing issue because I first tried a timeout of 100 ms, which wasn't sufficient.

Unfortunately I haven't yet found a better solution.

Comment: why delay of 2 seconds, when you can use an asynchronous callback

Comment: The callback was not firing consistently for me.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know how but `ng-href="/signout"` solved my problem. Previously I have used service to logout, but instead I've used it directly.

Comment: I'm not using Angular so this doesn't make any sense. :/