# Node.Js + express + Passport : Can't logout user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I wrote a JS script for a webserver that includes authentication using the passport and the digest strategy. I am not using sessions, but I have tried using sessions and it does not change the results. The browser requests the "/login" route and displays a built-in login dialog. Authentication works fine, but I can't get the user to "logout." The problem seems to be that the browser remembers the login credentials and resends them automatically. The end result is that the user must close the browser completely to log out, but that is a problem for this application. I know that there must be a way to tell the browser not to do this, but I haven't figured it out.

I figured out a hack to get the browser to display the login dialog again; force the authentication function to return a false. However, I haven't figured out a way to do this per-session. Right now, if one person logs out, everyone gets logged out. It's not a workable solution.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? One thing I'm wondering is whether I'm returning the proper response to the browser when it POSTs to the /logout route (see end). I return res.json(""), but maybe there's a different response I should send to tell the browser to forget the credentials for the session?

My code follows. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

T

```
var passport = require('passport'), 
    DigestStrategy = require('passport-http').DigestStrategy;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(
        "/", //the URL throught which you want to access to you static content
        express.static('./www') //where your static content is located in your filesystem
    );
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keep moving forward' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);


});
app.listen(80); //the port you want to use


/**
 * CORS support.
 */

app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  if (!req.get('Origin')) return next();
  // use "*" here to accept any origin
  // For specific domain, do similar: http://localhost'
  // Use an array for multiple domains, like [http://localhost', 'http://example.com' ]
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});


//
// Configure passport authentication
//


// Used to force the browser to display the login screen again.
var forceLogin = false;
passport.use(new DigestStrategy({ qop: 'auth' },
  function(username, done ) { 

  if ( !forceLogin )
  {
    return done(null, username, "nimda");
  }
  else
  {
    //
    // Forces the browser to request the user name again by returning a failure to its last request.
    //
    console.log ( "forcing user to log in"  );
    forceLogin = false;
    return done(null, false);
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

    console.log( "serialize user " + user.toString() );
    done(null, user.toString());
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log( "deserialize user " + id.toString() );
    done(null, id);
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('digest', { session: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log( "/login");
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    res.json({ id: req.user.id, username: req.user.username });
 }); 

app.post('/logout', function(req, res){

  req.logOut();

  // NOTE: Same results as req.logout
  //
  //  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
  //   res.redirect('/'); 
  //  });

  res.redirect("/");

  // flag to force a login
  forceLogin = true;

  console.log( "logout");

  // Is this the proper return to the browser?
  return res.json("");
});
```

Comment: Using global variable `forceLogin` is a **very** bad idea, because it will be shared across all requests from all your users.

Comment: Agreed, as I mentioned in my original post. That's why I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: shouldn't it be `app.get('/logout')` http://passportjs.org/guide/logout/

Comment: I don't see why app.post or app.get would make a difference. In any case, I tried it and the results were the same.

Comment: `app` is a global variable too. So, using `app.set`/`app.get` is the same thing as using global variables. `res.session` is the right place to store session-specific data.

Comment: I agree with using res.session, but I need to pass res.session to the passport authentication function somehow. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 7):

You could try the following

```
req.session.destroy()
req.logout()
res.redirect('/')
```

Saving the new state of the session is important if you're using some form a session store for persistent sessions (eg. Redis). I tried the above code with a similar setup and it seems to work for me

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758207/why-is-passportjs-in-node-not-removing-session-on-logout

Comment: req.session.destroy() makes the session object undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Server needs somehow notify web browser that he need to refresh login info (MD5 digests).
For that you can send 401 error code and **usually** browser will show login popup message.

By the way, all these tricks with sessions are useless because browser already have all required info for automatic logging in.

So you can try next code:

```
req.logout();
res.send("logged out", 401);
```

Comment: Was trying to logout using passport-http and this oneliner saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but I found this thread on Google while searching for answer and nothing worked for me. Finally, I was able to solve it so thought I could post solution here for anyone that might read this in the future.

---

So basically, I use node.js, express, passport(local) and rethinkdb as my storage, and I was having problem with `req.logout();` not logging me out.

My setup:

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var passport = require( 'passport' );
var session = require( 'express-session' );
var RDBStore = require( 'express-session-rethinkdb' )( session );
```

I tried a lot of stuff and nothing was working, so finally I decided to manually do it, by removing session record from database myself.

Here is the code I used:
    app.get( '/logout', function ( req, res, next ) {

```
    if ( req.isUnauthenticated() ) {

        // you are not even logged in, wtf
        res.redirect( '/' );

        return;

    }

    var sessionCookie = req.cookies['connect.sid'];

    if ( ! sessionCookie ) {

        // nothing to do here
        res.redirect( '/' );

        return;

    }

    var sessionId = sessionCookie.split( '.' )[0].replace( 's:', '' );

    thinky.r.db( 'test' ).table( 'session' ).get( sessionId ).delete().run().then( function( result ) {

        if ( ! result.deleted ) {

            // we did not manage to find session for this user
            res.redirect( '/' );

            return;

        }

        req.logout();
        res.redirect( '/' );

        return;

    });

});
```

So I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Awesome reply!  Would it be cheeky to ask how you setup the passport-local to connect with rethinkdb?  I am stumped on the creation process of storing the values and password hashing etc.  Many thanks!

Comment: I just came on here to post this exact answer. I too ended up doing this manually, and am using rethinkdb as my session store, and have the exact same logic.

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect('/')` will end the response, you can not call subsequently write(), end(), send(), json() ...etc

Just like this:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

deserializeUser should return a user instead of id:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    findUser(id, function(err, user) {
       if(err) {
          done(err)
       } else {
          done(null, user);
       }
    }
});
```

---

I have taken a short discussion, I realize that digest username/password store on browser (not on server), so req.logout not help, there no way to clear it from server. You just close browser and open again that mean logout.

You can use a variable in cookie or session to mark the session as logout, but I think we should not do not, because username/password still in browser.

It's digest!

Comment: I made those corrections, but the browser still doesn't "log out."

Comment: Ok, you gave me an idea. This appears to tell the browser that I've logged out:  app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
  
  req.logOut();
  console.log( "logout");
  res.send(401, "unauthorized");
});

Comment: No, it does not, which means my solution didn't work.