# nodejs+express+passort local 404 error when trying to logout

Tags: node.js, logout, passport-local

I am trying to add logout feature using passport local strategy.

I followed the solutions discussed [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/logout), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21670872/2320784) and [here](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.VkzW52SrQy4)

I added a

```
 a(href='/logout') logout
```

link in my index.jade file.

In my app.js I added the following:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    console.log("trying to logout....")
    req.session.destroy()
    req.logout()
    res.redirect('/signin');
});
```

But when I click the logout href It goes to my 404 page. In the browser url I see that it is attempting to go to:

```
localhost:3030/logout
```

I event added an empty `logout.jade` view but it makes no difference.

What am i doing wrong?

Also - I do not see the `console.log("trying to logout...")` message in my terminal... so it looks like it never reached the correct method.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't restarted your Node server? Looks like it should work.

Comment: I have restarted it several times...

Comment: Do you have a route like `app.get('/:id')` declared *before* your logout route? What might be happening is that your request can be caught by the first route and genuinely not finding anything with id === 'logout', resulting in an 404 error. Can you confirm it is not happening? PS.: Routing order matters a lot

Comment: @renatoargh I did not add a logout route.. i have made no changes in my routes.js file

Comment: @renatoargh thank you for mentioning order! that was the problem indeed.

Comment: @renatoargh may I ask you to explain why in this example of adi's that order would matter?  I am having the same problem but in an auth.js file that just has routes for signup, login, and logout "router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {". I can't see how order would matter in my case. If you could take a moment and share with me some insight it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer thanks to @renatoargh  pointing out that order of routes matter.
Somewhat annoyed that the passport docs don't mention this!!

**BEFORE:**

```
app.use(route.notFound404);

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    console.log("trying to logout....")
    req.session.destroy()
    req.logout()
    res.redirect('/signin');
});
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    console.log("trying to logout....")
    req.session.destroy()
    req.logout()
    res.redirect('/signin');
});

app.use(route.notFound404);
```