# router.get function not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js for a basic log in/log out system. For some reason, the `router.get('/signout', function(req, res))` is not being called when I run http://localhost:3000/auth/signout on Advanced rest client. Instead I am getting a Internal Server Error: 500. Login works just fine, but signout does not. Here is my app.js and authenticate.js:

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//Initialize models
require('./models/models.js');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/chirp-test");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'super duper secret'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); //This creates a unique has for our session


//Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport-init');
initPassport(passport);

app.use('/auth', authenticate);
app.use('/api', api);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Authenticate.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport){

    //sends successful login state back to angular
    router.post('/success', function(req, res){
        console.log('successful');
        res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
    });

    //sends failure login state back to angular
    router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
    });

    //log in
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', { failureRedirect: '/auth/failure' }),
        function(req, res) {
            //res.redirect('/auth/success');
            res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
        });


    //sign up
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));

    //log out
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Signing out...');
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have registered nothing under "/". So when "auth/logout" call redirect to redirect("/"), I guess client is redirected but goes into your "error handler" which sends a 500 error...

Comment: -> try redirect to "api/" instead; it seems to be the root of your app if I understand how you structured it.

Comment: Unfortunately the console is not logging the signout either, so it's as if it's not calling the function at all. Changed it but still not working

Comment: So the error might come from `req.logout()`... Are you sure some kind of security is not preventing req.logout to be called with get query ?

Comment: Maybe this will hep http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758207/why-is-passportjs-in-node-not-removing-session-on-logout/#answer-19132999

Comment: Appreciate the help, but still no dice. Again, it's not even running the `console.log('Signing out...')`, so I don't know if it's something with the initial call or what.

Comment: Oups sorry I read to quickly .. do you know if the 500 error comes from your custom handler or from anywhere else ?

Comment: Not sure, do you know a quick way to find out?